# Change Yii CActiveRecord column attribute value in case of storage array

Tags: php, yii, yii-cactiverecord

I have CActiveRecord model **Game** which attribute **game_data** stores the data of the game. In such way I stored the data (within beforeSave method):

```
$this->data = gzcompress(json_encode($this->data));
```

I extract data in the following way(withinn afterFind method):

```
$this->data = json_decode(gzuncompress($this->data), true);
```

After that I want to manipulate with the **game_data** attribute(add/change/delete), but the code returned an unexpected result for me.
Code and my research:

```
var_dump($this->data); // data that already stored in db for this game 
array(1) {
  ["provably_fair"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["server_seed"]=>
    string(32) "dKOsfTsGvmvZe0VW6bcFnIhJKXDesKeM"
  }
}
```

I am trying to add new property and value:

```
$this->data['provably_fair']['client_seed'] = $clientSeed;
```

But content of **$this->data** not change:

```
var_dump($this->data);
array(1) {
  ["provably_fair"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["server_seed"]=>
    string(32) "dKOsfTsGvmvZe0VW6bcFnIhJKXDesKeM"
  }
}
```

How I can modify data of this CActiveRecord attribute and whether it is possible?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. I think you make var_dump before changin property or for another model or you don't save changes.